# How do I save array of data from laravel blade to database

Tags: php, laravel

I have this dumped output from the Laravel blade. In this, you can notice there is an array of amounts of data. Now, How do you save all the data, including an array, to the database?

**Data From Form blade**

```
array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "JjZqQiTv304JU65DNCli4MSjOsO0aqB84KVu8UgB"
  "category" => "Equestrian"
  "logistics" => "Barloworld"
  "currency" => "USD"
  "descriptions" => "Dolore labore cillum"
  "user_id" => "33"
  "m_description" => "Test"
  "ddate" => "2021-07-08"
  "amount" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "300"
    1 => null
  ]
]
```

**Controller**

```
        $data = $request->all();
        dd($data);
         $data = new Order();
        
         $data->amount = $request->get('amount');
         $data->m_description = $request->get('m_description');
         $data->ddate = $request->get('ddate');
         $data->currency = $request->get('currency');
         $data->descriptions = $request->get('descriptions');
         $data->logistics = $request->get('logistics');
         $data->category = $request->get('category');
         $data->code = $request->get('code');
         $data->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
         $data->save();
```

Comment: You could use whatever way that suits you to store it, such as implode the array in to coma separated values or encode it in to json. And retrieve it accordingly

Comment: So you either json encode the array or you normalize your database and save the data into another table

Comment: @Abhishek I am new, can you show me how?

Comment: Pretty much. Depends on the data and how you want it

Comment: @Aless55 I am new, can you show me how?

Comment: In `Order Model` add column to casts property


     protected $casts = ['amount' => 'array']

Also you can filter null values before storing


    $data->amount =array_filter($request->amount);

Answer (score 2):

To save array you will have to use JSON format. Sometimes, you can use pivot tables to solve this problem but it has no sence to have pivot table for amount.

```
$data->amount = json_encode($request->get('amount'));
```

When getting data from database, you can make [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) on model, or method which will
`return json_decode($this->amount)`

If you would provide more information about what exactly could be in amount, I could answer better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use model casting for array store in database

refer this link

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

```
    protected $casts = [
            'amount' => 'array',
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the data into a string by using either [json_encode($array)](https://www.php.net/json_encode) or [serialize($array)](https://www.php.net/serialize). And then save the string to your database.